# Display frame around an expression in LyX (/LaTeX)

Tags: latex, lyx

Is it possible to draw a frame around an expression? For example if I presented a calculation, I want to draw attention to the result by drawing a "box" around it.

I've seen it done in some articles in LaTeX. Is it possible to do in LyX without ERT? Otherwise, how is it done in LaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\boxed`.

> ```
> \boxed{\nabla\cdot B = 0}
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: Make sure ams math package is used: `\usepackage{amsmath}`